# Mercurial:Remove last commit

Tags: mercurial

I was working in default, but thought to be working in another branch.
I commited, but didn't push.

Now I want to change branches and commit the changes to another branch, but also dont want the commit to go to default.

How do I undo that commit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are still in the *draft* phase (not pushed elsewhere yet), use the built-in extension `hg strip <rev>` command. Otherwise, you should do a `hg backout`, which will reverse the changeset.

In case you still need the commit you made, I suggest you `export` it to `import` it again in the correct branch, before stripping.

Comment: Also `hg rollback` can be useful if you haven't pushed changes yet.

Comment: @black_wizard True, mostly if you want to keep track of the wrong changeset!

Comment: Is "strip" an extention too? My hg help output does not list it as a valid command.

Comment: @Alex yes, it is a built-in extension; to enable it edit your `.hgrc` and under the `[extensions]` section add `strip=`

Answer (score 1):

If "another branch" already exist, you **must** move changeset to it, using `hg rebase` ([rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) have to be enabled)